# getElementsByTagName().setAttribute(); don't work in IE8

Tags: javascript

I am trying to convert input box to button. it's working well in all the browsers accept IE8.

HTML code

```
<input value="click here"></input>
```

JavaScript Code

```
document.getElementsByTagName("INPUT")[0].setAttribute("type","button");
```

Comment: How does it not work in IE8? Do you see any error messages? Anything in the JS console in dev tools?

Comment: Indeed, you can't change the `type` of an `<input>` element in IE8 and older. You have to recreate it with the correct type. Why would you want to, anyway?

Comment: you can't do it in IE, cos of security reason

Comment: @AshishRatan Rather *obscure* security reasons, anyway, since they dropped this behavior later. But hey, you may never know with all the legacy features of IE. It's just that I don't know what they could possibly be. You can't even change the `name` of an input field (!).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since IE8 doesn't let you change the type of your input, you'll have to create a new element that mimics the old one, and put it where the old one was.

```
var button = document.createElement("INPUT");
var input = document.getElementsByTagName("INPUT")[0];
for(var i = 0, attrs = input.attributes, l = attrs.length; i < l; i++)
  button.setAttribute(attrs.item(i).nodeName, attrs.item(i).nodeValue);
button.setAttribute("type", "button");
var parent = input.parentNode;
parent.replaceChild(button, input);
```

Comment: Why is there a loop here

Comment: @Jhawins to set all the atributes identically, of course!

Comment: @FlorianMargaine he's looping over the attributes of the first input, not over the inputs, though.

Comment: I don't know what you heard, but line 2 defines `input` as a single element. No looping. Are you trying to change *every* attribute?

Comment: @Jhawins he's copying every attribute to the new element

Comment: It _still_ breaks event handlers, though

Comment: @jan-dvorak I replace text field with button, for that I must create it previously, also I must add attributes of textfield to button before replace it.

Comment: @SargisMarkosyan can't you just change the type? If not, would you please add into the answer why it isn't possible?

Comment: @jan-dvorak Please check comments of question, there are some reasons, I don't know exactly way it is not possible.